# "The direction traveled"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, direct-objects

I have always found use of the phrase "the direction traveled" a bit odd, though not as striking as "travel a direction". People travel a distance and travel **in** a direction, but do not **travel a direction.* However, examples of this phrase abound on Google Books:

> A moving van traveled 200 mi west and 70 mi south. Find the distance from the point of origin to the destination, and the direction traveled.
>
> Uniform velocity means that the distances and the direction traveled by an object during a given unit of time do not change throughout the motion.
>
> A compass may also be used to determine the direction traveled on each leg of the outward journey, or the direction may be estimated from the twists and turns taken, sounds, smells, or even the earth's magnetic field.
>
> While the quarry moves from point to point, the squad follows the string of physical evidence along the track line and notes the direction traveled, evidence found, and locations visited.
>
> It would have been a physical impossibility for a gun, falling and striking the floor and exploding from the contact, to have discharged a bullet in the direction traveled by the bullet which killed Ramón Wong.
>
> The longer the jump the wider the variation in the distance and the direction traveled.

What does the passive structure work but not the active form of the same phrase? Is there a name for this grammar phenomenon?

Comment: The answer is in the first example: we traveled 200 mi west. No **in**. "The direction traveled was correct but the compass wasn't working". Travel north, south, west, east etc.(to travel a direction) No in. One needn't say: the direction in which we traveled, unless required."What direction did you travel?"

Comment: @Lambie Yeah that part makes perfect sense. But there does seem to be a bit of inconsistency here. We "travel north". But we don't "travel that/the direction", do we?

Comment: Yes,we traveled a southerly direction.

Comment: Well, *"traveled a southerly direction"* returns 2 hits on Google, in stark comparison to *"traveled **in** a southerly direction"*'s 9,270 hits...

Comment: to travel north, south, east, west. north, south, eat and west are directions. You don't always need in. And google doesn't show everything. Thank goodness. These things are internalized. As I said,the answer is in the first sentence, no **in**. Google: "the direction traveled" About 9,170 results (0.48 seconds)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "travel a direction" is wrong? Provide an example of such an incorrect sentence. *Up*, for instance, is an adjective. I'm not aware of any sentence that can put an article in front of an adjective unless a noun follows it. And even then, many combinations of article+adjective+noun cannot be used. *Travel* and directional adjectives don't have a monopoly. Incidentally, *distance* is a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment @EddieKal. This sentence is grammatical: "I *travel a direction* unknown to you." This sentence is ungrammatical: "I *travel a left*." What are you actually asking?

Comment: The direction traveled in that first case is west-southwest.